# arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6')

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, ecmascript-6, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

Currently I'm running my tests with protractor/grunt but I'm getting the follow error message:

```
'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6').
```

I think my **.jshintrc** file is not being read, because I've added this condition.

**.jshintrc**

```
{ 
  "esversion": 6 
}
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
jshint : {
  all: ["tests/API/**/*.js"],
  options: {
    undef: true,
    mocha: true,
    node: true,
    jshintrc: true,
    esversion: 6,
    globals: {
      require: true,
      module: true,
      console: true,
      esversion: 6,
      }
  },
  ui: ["tests/UI/**/*.js"],
  options: {
    undef: true,
    mocha: true,
    node: true,
    jshintrc: true,
    esversion: 6,
    globals: {
      require: true,
      module: true,
      console: true,
      esversion: 6,
      jshintrc: true,
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you use `options` and `globals` 2 times as keys if they have the same values and are in the same object depth?

Comment: What @GGG may be asking is that you have the same `options` object in your `jshint` object for no apparent reason.  Are the keys `all` and `ui` supposed to be point to objects, which each have their own `options`?

Comment: Guys, I've removed it but my problem still occurs.

Comment: This is a bit old, but have you tried settings `esnext: true` inside `options`?

Answer (score 58):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding this block of code at the top of each file.js that accused the error

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
```

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: If the IDE supports extensions, then install jshint extension :)

Comment: For me worked. I am using VSCode on MacOS. Thank you.

Answer (score 56):

It is not possible to add `/*jshint esversion: 6 */` in each file.js file.

Instead of above, please do below changes if you are using Visual Studio Code: -

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. File -> Preferences -> Settings
3. Default User Settings -> JSHint configuration
4. look for `"jshint.options": {},`
5. change it to `"jshint.options": {"esversion": 6},` by clicking on Edit on the left

Comment: This worked for me. After step 3, under the config section, click "Edit in settings.json". In my settings, there was no jshint.options, so I had to add it.

Answer (score 18):

You can do more project-specific settings by following these steps.

1. Create a folder with the name of `.vscode` at the root of your project directory
2. Create a file with the name `settings.json`
3. Add the following content into it.

> ```
> {
>   "jshint.options": {
>     "esversion": 6
>   }
> }
> ```

You can add some more settings to keep things consistents across your team.

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true, 
    "jshint.options": {
        "esversion": 6
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the following into your `package.json`:

```
"jshintConfig": {
  "esversion": 6
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem after I installed JSHint. The process for me to solve this problem as below:
Preference -> setting -> Extensions -> JSHint Configuration -> options -> add 
"jshint.options": {"esversion": 6}
Done.