# Error in gulp --production with jquery function

Tags: jquery, laravel, gulp

I have jquery which does some filtering in my project. when I run the project locally it works fine. so when I run `gulp --production` it's giving the error like this

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)'

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input.ConfigBundleCheckbox', function(e) {
  $('.assetIDConfig').hide()
    .filter(function() {
      var checkedItems = [];
      $(".ConfigBundleCheckbox:checked").each(function(e) {
        checkedItems.push(parseInt(this.value));
      });
      var x = JSON.parse("[" + $(this).data("category") + "]");
      var y = checkedItems;
      var found = y.reduce((included, num) => included && x.includes(num), true);
      if (!checkedItems.length) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return found;
      }
    }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="baseTable JobTable table text-center table-stripped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center">Select</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheck1" value="9" id="9" class="js-switch ConfigBundleCheckbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        Planer Operator
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCheck2" value="10" id="10" class="js-switch ConfigBundleCheckbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        Banksman
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="ConfigTable JobTable table text-center table-stripped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center">Description</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="ConfigMatch">
    <tr class="assetIDConfig" data-category="11,9">
      <td>
        Planer with Operator
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <button data-bundleid="5" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Select</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="assetIDConfig" data-category="11,9,10">
      <td>
        Planer with Operator and Banksman
      </td>
      <td style="text-align: center">
        <button data-bundleid="6" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Select</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above jquery code, it says there is a syntax error at the line

> var found = y.reduce((included, num) => included && x.includes(num),
>   true);

But I m not getting what's the syntax error in that line so I checked the syntax error using this website `http://jshint.com/` and it says

> 'arrow function syntax (=>)' is only available in ES6 (use 'esversion:
>   6').

I'm not getting what I need to do ? can somebody help me with this issue how to alter this line to achieve my results?

My `gulpfile.js` contents:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(mix => {
   mix.sass('app.scss');
   mix.copy('resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/fonts', 'public/fonts');
   mix.copy('resources/assets/vendor/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
   mix.styles([
       'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css',  
       'resources/assets/vendor/animate/animate.css',
       'resources/assets/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/select2/select2.min.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/gridForm/gridforms.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/iCheck/custom.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/switchery/switchery.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/ladda/ladda-themeless.min.css',

       'resources/assets/css/plugins/dropzone/basic.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.css',
       // 'resources/assets/css/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css',
       // 'resources/assets/css/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css',
       'resources/assets/css/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.css',
       'resources/assets/css/custom_style.css'
   ], 'public/css/vendor.css', './');
   mix.scripts([
       'resources/assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/dataTables/datatables.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.rowsGroup.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js',
       // 'resources/assets/js/plugins/fullcalendar/moment.min.js',
       'resources/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/datapicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js',

       'resources/assets/vendor/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js',
       'resources/assets/vendor/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
       'resources/assets/vendor/pace/pace.min.js',


       'resources/assets/js/plugins/select2/select2.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/gridForm/gridforms.js',

       'resources/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/dropzone/dropzone.js',

       'resources/assets/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/switchery/switchery.js',

       'resources/assets/js/plugins/typehead/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js',
       // 'resources/assets/js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
       //'resources/assets/js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/peity/jquery.peity.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/custom.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/ladda/spin.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/ladda/ladda.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/plugins/ladda/ladda.jquery.min.js',
       'resources/assets/js/app.js'
   ], 'public/js/app.js', './');

});
```

Any suggestions, Please!

Comment: Does this answer help you? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/42870745/5687152](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42870745/5687152)

Comment: Could you check your `Gulpfile.js` , there you have probably a lint task which throws this error while being executed, since it's not setup for the ES6. All you have to do is to add `esversion: 6` to the linter (JSHint) options inside the task.

Comment: @mabe02: no It did not help me

Comment: @RamizWachtler: where I need to add that?

Comment: @06011991 `Gulpfile.js` , there should be a linting task (It might be helpful to attach the contents of `Gulpfile.js` to your question)

Comment: @RamizWachtler: can you check I have added the contents of gulpfile.js in my question

Comment: Since you are using Elixir, I'm not sure if that has something to do with the version of it or not. You could try to update the package. Unfortunately I've never worked with Elixir in combination with ES6 before.

Comment: Yeah okay, will try doing that. Thank you